# Create SVN branch from changes in trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, trunk

I'm in a stupid situation: I have done some changes in a working copy of the TRUNK. Since the changes have not been tested, I'd like to transfer all the changes to a branch. According to the manual of Tortoise, Switch will lose all my modifications. Is there any way to keep my changes in the working copy and save them in a branch in the repository.

Answer (score 13):

Create a branch from your working copy instead of the repository. That way you wont lose anyting

Comment: Do you mean Branch/Tag?
But how could the default Link to the working copy be changed?

Comment: You can switch after that. Your changes will be committed to the new branch and there is no problem with switch. You will lose noithing

Comment: In TortoiseSVN click Branch/Tag and then instead of selecting the HEAD or specific revision choose the working copy radio button. That is what Midhat is talking about.

Comment: @Biran thanks for the explanation. Yes thats what I am talking abt

Answer (score 9):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are working on a copy that you checked out off `TRUNK`, but you haven't committed the changes yet.

In that case, it's easy to solve this problem:

1. Create a branch off `TRUNK`: `svn cp <base URL> <new branch URL>`
2. Switch to the new branch (specified by `<new branch URL>` above)
3. Now your working copy should point to the `<new branch URL>`
4. Commit your changes

Since you haven't committed anything to `TRUNK`, the `TRUNK` version of the project is left unmodified

Comment: Nice clear explanation! (2) could use an example command "svn switch <new branch URL>"

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. But you can make a patch, then switch and lose your changes, then apply the patch to your branch.

Richt-click on your working copy top-most folder, choose Tortoise SVN > Create Patch. Choose the files to be included (usually all changes) and save it somewhere.

Then switch.

Then richt-click on the working copy again (which now points to the branch), and choose Tortoise SVN > Apply Patch. You'll get a menu where you can right-click and choose apply all. Save the changes and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try my hand with this method.

Comment: It seems this answer was downvoted (though it has a score of 0, I can see it in my Reputation settings). Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Create a patch of the changes and then apply it to any branch or working copy that you like.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think my answer is very relevant to the question.